# Selenium WebDriver Slider

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I need it to move a slider bar to the right. I've seen on other posts that WebElement is used but I'm unsure still.

here is what I tried:

```
 WebElement Slider = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("#tipAmount"));
    Thread.sleep(3000);

    Actions moveSlider = new Actions(driver);
    Action action = (Action) moveSlider.dragAndDropBy(Slider, 30, 0).build();

    moveSlider.perform();
```

Comment: what result did you get?

Comment: what is the exception message you got?

Comment: The exception message is
java.lang.ClassCastException: org.openqa.selenium.interactions.CompositeAction cannot be cast to javax.swing.Action
 at com.firefoxtester.webdriver.FireFoxTest.dtestTip(FireFoxTest.java:73)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
 at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
 at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)

Comment: at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
 at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
 at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
 at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
 at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
 at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)

Comment: at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
 at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
 at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
 at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
 at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)

Comment: at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26)
 at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:27)
 at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
 at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
 at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:68)

Comment: Please do not post code snippets and/or huge texts in comments. Please [edit] your question rather.

Comment: When I figured out I was using the wrong action Import

Comment: I'm having problems finding the slider-handle

Answer (score 0):

I haven't done many Actions but from what I can tell from looking at a sample it looks like you need to do

```
action.perform();
```

instead of

```
moveSlider.perform();
```